# Is there any way to build a tamperproof forum like Reddit?

Tags: database, security

Following the recent incident on reddit (viz https://www.reddit.com/r/The_Donald/comments/5ekdy9/the_admins_are_suffering_from_low_energy_have/dad5sf1/) where the CEO of Reddit changed content of certain posts without any notification to anyone.

Is there any way to secure a forum database so it's tamperproof even when accessed by root? It doesn't have to be tamperproof in the sense that root couldn't change it, but it should leave a clear mark.

I'm thinking something along the lines of cryptographic signature of the posts by the poster where (maybe) his password could be used to sign the post while the hash on server could be used to validate that the content is unchanged. However, it would be prefarable to not request the user password every time he wants to post something.

**UPDATE:** It should remain centralized, so blockchain doesn't really work here.

Also, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible to create a tamper-proof data storage, e.g. using blockchain tech. A blockchain prevents deletion of content since each cryptographically signed block refers to the signature of the predecessor blocks. However, this requires many participants that contribute data storage and processing power. If there is a disagreement, the blockchain is split. Everyone must choose which of the two forks they believe. A change can therefore not be prevented, but it can't go unnoticed.

<sup>(**Edit:** Note that a public storage mechanism without deletion is ethically undesirable. Such a system could be abused to distribute hate speech, perform copyright infringement, publish sensitive data without authorization, distribute child pornography, spread bomb building manuals, …. And everyone participating in that storage mechanism would be complicit. These problems are similar to BitTorrent, except that BitTorrent can be used for legitimate purposes without inadvertently also helping illicit causes. It is therefore extremely likely that an everyone-can-post blockchain database would be effectively illegal in large parts of the world.)</sup>

If you only want to prevent changes to the content, a centralized data store is possible. All data entries would have to be cryptographically signed, and we would need a public/private key management scheme. If a post is changed, the signature would no longer match the posting user's public key. It would still be possible to replace a post with similar content, but signed by a different key. Therefore, the key distribution and more importantly the private keys must be kept separate from the data storage provider.

All of this means it's impossible to create a user-friendly tamper-proof forum on the web. Each end user must manage their private key themselves. If they want to use another device, they will need to copy their key to that device. If they lose their key, they would no longer be able to post under their identity. Any signatures and signature verifications would have to happen locally. If you don't trust the forum provider, all of this must not happen within the user interface of the forum or they could exfiltrate your keys or display a tampered signature as OK.

Similar considerations apply to Email encryption: Why aren't all end users encrypting or signing all their emails? The No 1 problem are web mail services like Gmail – If you want to read your the decrypted email in the browser, you'd have to trust your web mail provider with your private key, which defeats the point of encrypting your email in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can think of one easy way to do this -- just PGP-sign your post on your local machine, with a local PGP client that you trust, and then post the signed message on the forum.

Other users can then verify the integrity of your post, with their locally trusted PGP client.

Of course, this requires you to have generated a private key, and then posted your public key somewhere easily accessible (ideally NOT the same forum you are posting to). And requires you to use some local client software.

Those of us old enough to remember Usenet should remember how we did public tamperproof forum postings back in the day  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the server sign new posts with a private (to the forum owner) anti-tamper key and send the signature back into the browser local storage of the user. Later on when a bad admin has tampered a post, the user can prove the original user content, as long as there is a date in it.

Comment: What happens when a user forges a signature, and claims that a mod has edited their post? A user can only raise the accusation that the signature changed, but it's impossible to prove anything with this scheme. The only way around that is if the end users and not the forum hold the keys with which the content is signed.

Comment: I agree, but can you explain what forging the signature here means?

Comment: My answer makes the assumption that there cannot be a forged signature until the private key was has been leaked. From then on, contradicting signatures can exist. The contradiction is the "clear mark" that the OP asked for.